# AS3, xmlSocket and encoding

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xmlsocket

I am working with `xmlSocket` and I have an encoding problem (I think). In Flash Builder, when I trace my `event.data` property I see data as expected but when I debug it, I see many unrecognized characters.

See image :

[image]

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grdqr.png)

When I use `Alert.show()` I see those unrecognized characters and when I work with substring methods and string methods, I have problem too.

Naturally, I want to work with the trace's version...

Encoding problem...? How to solve it ? I tried to work with byteArray without success.

NB: I can not modify or see the socket server code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was just non-ascii characters. The following code solved me :

```
var myString:String = event.data.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, "")
```